# Cannot tether Canon EOS digital camera to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: usb, mount, canon, camera, tether

For various reasons, I want to tether my Canon EOS Rebel T6 digital camera to my Ubuntu machine to take pictures using software such as Entangle. However my system does not recognize the camera upon plugging it in by USB. This has worked in the past (5+ years ago).

All the posts I've seen are from years ago (2014, 2012, etc.)
Neither gphoto2 or guvcview have worked. I have four machines all with negative results

- Ubuntu Studio 16.04,
- 2 x (HP Pavilion HPE/ Omen laptop) Ubuntu Studio 18.04
- Kubuntu 14.04.

I am looking for it to work on my 18.04 machines.

None of the similar issues I found here have any solutions.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Results...

```
~$ lsusb
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 058f:6362 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Card Reader/Writer
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 0a5c:217d Broadcom Corp. HP Bluethunder
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 192f:0416 Avago Technologies, Pte. ADNS-5700 Optical Mouse Controller (3-button)
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 04f2:1060 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 009 Device 002: ID 1058:25e2 Western Digital Technologies, Inc. 
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I ran `dmesg -w` (got an output) and then plugged in my Canon camera. Nothing happened. When I plugged in a logitech webcam to the same port, the output updated and gave the information of the webcam.

Comment: Run `dmesg -w`, and plug in your camera. [Edit] your post with the messages that appear after plugging in camera.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I ran dmesg -w, plugged in my camera and nothing happened. Just to be sure, I plugged in my logitech webcam to the same port and the terminal updated. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Try a different cable. Try the camera at a different computer. This way you'll know if it's the computer, cable or camera.

Comment: Do you have all dependencies installed?  [Entangle's FAQ](https://entangle-photo.org/faq/) gives a list of dependencies for their software.  I suspect that you might also need a driver from Canon, or one that the community has written for this camera

Comment: @Nmath never installed any additional software when using gphoto2. Anyway, a new USB device ***should*** produce some output in the kernel log (`dmesg`), even if it's totally unknown and unsupported.

Comment: The problem is consistent on all four of my machines using 14.04, 16.04 and 18.04. I've tried different usb cables to no effect, and the usb webcam DID produce an output.
I have all dependencies for Entanngle, however I believe the problem is why the camera is not recognized at all.

Answer (score 4):

Disabling Wi-Fi/NFC on the camera corrected the issue for me. This is with a Canon EOS Rebel T6 camera. If you do not disable this the camera apparently only communicates via wifi. I had installed the Canon app on my phone and had gotten the wifi control of the camera working, but failed to turn that off when I wanted to copy files from the camera via the USB cable.

Answer (score 1):

"Wi-Fi/NFC" should be set to Disable on the camera.